# Modify API OAuth Token Expire Time

Tags: rest, oauth, acumatica

Acumatica Version: 2019R1

I'm looking to either modify the expiry time on granted OAuth tokens using a Connected Application within Acumatica. Currently, my token is granted using the 'api' and the 'offline_access' scopes to be able to access the API, and to get a refresh token.

I am trying to avoid using any type of session/cookie-based authentication, as my system will be solely interacting with the Acumatica REST API from a complete external source, and cannot store any session/cookie-related data.

My ultimate end goal would allow my application a specific token for absolute concurrent access without the need for refreshing, but a longer expiry time would most likely suffice.

For background, I have looked within all of the help docs, and through each of the Acumatica Developer Training courses, but none of them explicitly state if the OAuth protocol is editable.

I've looked in the OAuth 2.0 Framework documentation at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749, but while it shows that it is possible to modify the token expiry time/completely remove the expiry, it has no specific information on how to modify it, since Acumatica implemented the framework.

Here is the x-www-form-urlencoded request body being sent to grant the initial token:

```
grant_type: <password>
client_id: <applicationID>@<company>
client_secret: <secret>
username: <username>
password: <password>
scope: api offline_access
```

Here is the response received from both the initial token request, as well as each request to refresh the token:

```
{
    "access_token": "<accesstoken>",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "refresh_token": "<refreshtoken>"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I am searching through, it seems that Acumatica uses IdentityServer3 to implement the OAuth API for Connected Applications. The clients are entered through the SM303010 screen where you can set the ClientSecrets and RedirectURIs. The attribute in IdentityServer3 to modify would be AccessTokenLifetime.

https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/configuration/clients.html

It is defaulted as 3600 seconds (one hour) and does not seem to give you any entry point to modify.

I would verify with Support, but if it is not available, you can always request the feature to be added on https://feedback.acumatica.com

Comment: Yep, it is exactly like this: there is no configuration not customization point for that in Acumatica right now.

Comment: Hi  - we have a similar need. We have an external nodejs application that will be interacting with Acumatica over the rest apis. we are using this way "Resource Owner Password Credentials". We also do not need the token to expire nor do we really want to deal with managing the refresh token process either. How did you end up approaching the problem?